# Application Insights - user_AuthenticatedId to Azure UPN

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights

I have hooked up a Power App to Azure Application Insights to track useage.

When the events are logged, the user ID is recorded with the Azure Active Directory ID (a Guid).

Whilst I can interrogate AAD for the user ID manually to get the UPN, is there any way in the App Insights Data Explorer to map the user ID to the UPN.

```
pageViews 
| where timestamp  > datetime(2021-02-04 14:30:00)
| project user_AuthenticatedId, '[UPN]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was a bit of a round-a-bout way of doing this, but I created a Power Automate flow using various HTTP REST calls.

Firstly, I pulled the list of User IDs from App Insights using the REST Api with a query and then cycled over the response making HTTP requests to the MS Graph API requesting the user information.

It needed an Azure App Registration with appropriate security access to call into Graph but it was a simple task end the end.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, short answer is no for default telemetry like page view. Inbuilt telemetry does not capture any PII for data compliance (for example, UPN user@example.com reveals the user email).

However, you can write custom trace to capture that. Example:

```
Trace(
   "App Feedback",
   TraceSeverity.Information,
       {
         UserName: User().FullName,
         UserEmail: User().Email
       }
     );
```

Note: If you are logging any personnel data, you will need to consider any data compliance obligations, such as GDPR, that you might also need to implement.

For details, refer [Analyze app telemetry using Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/application-insights).

Comment: I don't actually need to store the data. At the moment, the Power App is currently open-access but we wanted to restrict access and wanted to see who is actually using it so that we could create an Azure security group with those members.However, I did come up with the solution as per my own "accepted" answer. But your point is well valid in that you cannot simply just pull out and store user PII data